# Remove First 3 Characters in Select Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this select statement:

```
SELECT a.TASK_ID, a.COMPANY, b.INVOICED, b.VALUE AS companyid FROM b_report_week a
INNER JOIN b_company b ON a.COMPANY = b.VALUE
```

The above statement doesn't work because b.VALUE always has CO_ before the number, for example:

```
CO_123
CO_193
CO_838
```

However, if the first 3 characters are stripped off in the SELECT statement then it will would as it would leave:

```
123
193
838
```

Your help would be appreciated, I've looked through SO and cannot find the correct solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the MySQL documentation?

Comment: MySQL SUBSTRING() returns a specified number of characters from a particular position of a given string. [link](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, put the string back when you do the `join`:

```
SELECT a.TASK_ID, a.COMPANY, b.INVOICED, b.VALUE AS companyid
FROM b_report_week a INNER JOIN
     b_company b
     ON concat('CO_', a.COMPANY) = b.VALUE;
```

Comment: Worked a treat! Thank you

Comment: Yes, I was going to but it doesn't let you until 10 minutes have passed.  Done now

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.TASK_ID, a.COMPANY, b.INVOICED, b.VALUE AS companyid FROM b_report_week a
INNER JOIN b_company b ON RIGHT(a.COMPANY,3) = b.VALUE
```

I assume the value would be 3 characters always.. This would help you if your values are always 3 characters.